# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /usr/www/users/weddiycvvx/index.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get MySql to connect. Please assist, I'm fairly new to PHP.

```
mysql_connect('sql5.jnb3.host-h.net', 'user', 'password');
```

Comment: does your php support mysql?

Comment: you need to enable mysql in PHP

Comment: I hope those credentials are fake...

Comment: Congrats, you've just posted your database login onto a public website for the entire world to see. GO CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: The database info was fake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the php mysql module.

you can get it either from your distributions package manager or from pecl.php.net.

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file, search for a line like this `;extension=php_mysql.dll` and simply remove the `;` character from the start of the line. If you do not have the mysql extension installed, check out this link for instruction on how to install it : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php.
According to link above, you should also specify your extensions directory :

`extension_dir="YOUR_EXTENSION_DIRECTORY"`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `;extension=php_mysql.o`? I'm not much of a Linux user but I'm not sure it supports dlls.

Comment: I didn't see the OS mentioned anywhere, so it's OK but *only for Windows*. ;-)

Depending on the OS and architecture, that could be an ".o", a ".so", or a ".dll" and possibly even something else....

Answer (score -3):

Make connection like this

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");

mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
```

Comment: in mysql, `$link` is not mandatory. This applies for mysqli

Comment: In this case, "$link" refers to your variable "$con"....